# Form / Workflow: How to have a form submission email the correct person

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, custom-form, form

- One of the items in the form will give the user the ability to pick one a specific policy or standard.
- Each policy or standard will be connect to a specific person

  - So the user picks the selection and that person connected will get email when the form submitted

How do I set this up in SharePoint?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Best way is to create to separate lists:

1. Policy List: To store these policies/standards along with the name and email address of the reviewer.
2. Second list where you will have a lookup column from policies list. So that user will have the option to pick one specific policy on the form of this second list.

**To send Email Notification**:

1. Add workflow on item creation in second list.
2. Send Email notification to the email address of reviewer(you can get it from lookup or you can directly fetch it from policies list by passing the filter of policy/standard).

Comment: Have you tried this?